# How to enable OAuth 2.0 Authentication in Arure API Management Service?

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

I am trying to route the data of a Web service having REST API : http://demo.akeneo.com/api/rest/v1/categories

I am using Azure API Management Service for this. I have created an Azure API management service and a Blank API for same. I have created a GET method for this. While testing this API I have I am facing an Error as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store, private
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.akeneo.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-07f41c14e74157aff6fa6296dac0027c13e46705'; img-src 'self' data: ; frame-src * ; font-src 'self' data:
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 12 May 2020 07:05:18 GMT
expires: Tue, 12 May 2020 07:05:18 GMT
ocp-apim-trace-location: https://apimst3v04xlapwxf3c99avt.blob.core.windows.net/apiinspectorcontainer/9kvUzyqpMfhQQii4nn7e49QLxiE1-16?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=e9ETEXuY0pbzxyM%2FLBsJiidcrVL%2BROf1FnZ9652IDfw%3D&se=2020-05-13T07%3A05%3A18Z&sp=r&traceId=ba521452333d475b95521351d7ac19f3
pragma: no-cache
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="Service", error="access_denied", error_description="OAuth2 authentication required"
x-content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.akeneo.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-07f41c14e74157aff6fa6296dac0027c13e46705'; img-src 'self' data: ; frame-src * ; font-src 'self' data:
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-webkit-csp: default-src 'self' *.akeneo.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-07f41c14e74157aff6fa6296dac0027c13e46705'; img-src 'self' data: ; frame-src * ; font-src 'self' data:
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "OAuth2 authentication required"
}
```

When I change my Security to OAuth 2.0 it gives says No OAuth 2.0 servers were configured. 
Please can anyone help with how to configure the OAuth 2.0 Servers. Also, is the method I am using to in Azure API management Service to GET the data of the REST API correct. If there is some other work around, please specify.
[Image for reference  in the Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9EZH.png)

Comment: Is http://demo.akeneo.com/api/rest/v1/categories your web service api or the apim endpoint?

Comment: It is a web service API (REST API)

Comment: So your api is already protected by OAuth2 authentication? What is the provider?

Comment: akeneo is the provider. you can check it on their API specification for Authentication. In postman it is authenticated using Header.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how to configure the OAuth 2.0 Server, please refer to this guide.

[Configure an OAuth 2.0 authorization server in API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2#-configure-an-oauth-20-authorization-server-in-api-management).

Comment: Yes, I did go through it but it isn't helping me in my scenario.